# AngularJS: Reading a JSON from Disk rather from a REST service?

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs

I would like to store a JSON file on disk and I would like to have angular read and parse this.

I looked into $http and Restangular but it appears these only work with remote services and not physical files.

I was originally storing config info in a Constant object (angularJS) but this is quite difficult for a external program to parse this so i decided to store a JSON file but I am unsure how to read it back in.

I know JSON $.getJson from jquery may support but is there an alternative ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a little bit confused seeing the answers.

Do you mean something like...

```
$http.get('some.json').success(function(foo) { $scope.foo = foo; });
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/5uwpfYRKARjyxYBLKcmc?p=preview

Not sure if this is what you mean tbh.

Comment: So its just a relative path... I probably didn't explain correctly initially. Thanks for seeing through the dust !

Comment: You explained it correctly but I got confused with the answers. Glad the answer works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Serve your app from a webserver [Apache / nginx / node.js Express static], then drop your JSON file into some known path.

Then you can consume it as any RESTful service.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't have access to the file system, so accessing a file directly from angular is not possible. You will have to have angular interact with something that can access the file system, like node.js, nginx, apache ect. Then you can use `$http`.

Comment: So if its in my root directory do I just $http normally without passing the http:// due to it being relative ? Do you have an example?

Comment: If its in root, and available at `http://myjson.json` then you should be able to access it as expected. Relative paths should work fine, so long as the relative path is right.